# Python: Leer por fichero y implementar en una lista

Tags: python

Os tramito mi problema: Deseo leer un fichero en el cual se almacenan unas características. El fichero a leer tiene esta estructura tal que así:

1. Primera linea : Número de niveles totales... (20)
2. Línea con el numero de coches (8)

Las siguientes lineas indican los coches y sus características:

3. H132 ( Información : Este es un coche , H- Horizontal 1,3 posición en una matriz , 2 longitud
4. V112
5. ...

Hasta llegar al numero anterior de coches , nos encontraríamos posteriormente con otro nivel... Un ejemplo sería:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bien yo lo que quiero es hacer una lista de tamaño el numero total de niveles , 20 y por tanto que en cada nivel se almacene una lista nueva con los coches anteriores. Este es mi código actual:

```
 infile = open('niveles.txt', 'r')
 niv = 0
 h = 0
 nivel = []
 caracteristicas = []
 for line in infile:
     loncad = len(line)
 if loncad < 4: # Toma las cadenas , en este caso de numero de coches
         i = int(line)
         print (i)
         if i != 20:  # Si es distinto de 20 , numero de niveles
             niv +=1 # Contador de niveles...

 else:
    if loncad > 4: # Para las cadenas del coche...
       caracteristicas.append(line).
    nivel [niv] =  caracteristicas # Aquí recibo el error de asignación....


print (nivel)
```

El problema es que recibo error de rango y no logro comprenderlo...

> ```
>  Error recibido :
>
>  nivel [niv] =  caracteristicas
>
>  IndexError: list assignment index out of range
> ```

Comment: Creo que el formato se te ha trastocado pegando el código. Supongo que ese último `else` forma parte del primer if. Estaría bien que pusieras el código de error ya que da información de qué línea esta fallando.

Comment: Por cierto, para abrir achivos de texto es mejor usar el `with` ([documentación](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects))

Comment: Corregido , y indicado donde recibo el error así como lo expresa el compilador.

Comment: Vale , primer error arreglado , cambio la antigua asignación del for para la lista por : caracteristicas.append(line) ,edito el post indicando el error de Index en la lista nivel. He tratado de subsanarlo con nivel.insert(niv,caracteristicas) , pero me mete todo en la misma lista..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error se debe a que debes inicializar la lista `nivel` al principio de todo para que contenga dentro 20 listas donde almacenar los coches de cada nivel:

```
nivel = [list() for _ in range(20)]
```

Hay muchas otras cosas que se pueden simplificar, siguiendo tu idea podemos conseguir lo que deseas con:

```
nivel = [list() for _ in range(20)]
with  open('niveles.txt', 'r') as infile:
    niv = -1
    for line in infile:
        if len(line) < 4:
            if int(line) != 20:
                niv +=1 
        else:
            nivel[niv].append(line)
print (nivel)
```

De todas formas te complicas demasiado (o yo me complico demasiado, según se vea XD), bastan 4 lineas para hacer eso y es posible que se pueda mejorar usando por ejemplo expresiones regulares:

```
with open('niveles.txt', 'r') as f:
    aux = [line.rstrip() for line in f][1:]
    cochesNivel = ((i, int(n)) for i, n in enumerate(aux) if n.isdigit())
    niveles = [aux[i[0]+1:i[0]+i[1]+1] for i in cochesNivel]

    print(niveles)
```

- Usamos `with` para manejar el archivo, esto asegura que cuando termine el código el archivo será cerrado de forma segura.
- `aux` es una lista que contiene todas las lineas del archivo menos la primera (en realida no hace falta especificar 20 niveles si cada nivel viene especificado por el número de coches). Con `rstrip` eliminamos el fin de linea de la cadena, al leer cad linea del txt obtenemos una cadena como `'H232\n'`, con esto obtenemos `'H232'` que es lo que nos interesa.
- `cochesNivel` es un generador que nos busca todas las lineas que solo contienen digitos mediante el método `isdigit()` (esas son las que nos indican el numero de coches por nivel). Fijate que podemos crear 2000 coches por nivel, no tiene porque ser una cadena de menos de 4 letras. Para cada coincidencia se almacena una tupla conteniendo el indice donde está ese dato y el dato (el numero de coches por nivel).
- `niveles` es la lista de salida, usa los datos de `cochesNivel` para partir adecuadamente `aux` en cada nivel. Se crea usando list comprehensions.
- Si deseas usar la lista niveles fuera del `with` basta con declararla justo antes:

  ```
  niveles= list()
  with open('niveles.txt', 'r') as f:
      aux = [line.rstrip() for line in f][1:]
      cochesNivel = ((i, int(n)) for i, n in enumerate(aux) if n.isdigit())
      niveles = [aux[i[0]+1:i[0]+i[1]+1] for i in cochesNivel]

  print(niveles)
  ```

Para un txt de la forma:

> 3
>   8
>   H232
>   H113
>   V513
>   H143
>   V442
>   V352
>   H552
>   H562
>   8
>   H232
>   H112
>   V613
>   V123
>   V423
>   V513
>   V333
>   V623
>   3
>   H232
>   H113
>   V513

Obtenemos:

> [['H232', 'H113', 'V513', 'H143', 'V442', 'V352', 'H552', 'H562'], ['H232', 'H112', 'V613', 'V123', 'V423', 'V513', 'V333', 'V623'], ['H232', 'H113', 'V513']]

Creo que es esto lo que deseas. En este caso tenemos 3 listas dentro de la lista `niveles` (una por nivel) y en cada una almacenamos los coches que hay en ese nivel.

Comment: Solventado. Muchas gracias. Es que pasé de Java a Python por unos motivos... y bueno , hay cosas que si que se podrían compactar bastante la verdad jeje , más bien es que me tengo que mirar a fondo algunas funciones e. Realmente acaba de solventarlo  , otro problema que tenía era que la lista caracteristicas necesitaba ser reseteada y así pasaba correctamente los parametros , y tras incializar bien niveles me funcionaba correctamente .... Un saludo y muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

En vez de indexar caracteristicas usa append. Por ejemplo:

```
infile = open('niveles.txt', 'r')
niv = 0
h = 0
nivel = []
caracteristicas = []
lines = infile.readlines()
nivel.append(int(lines[0]))
numero_de_autos = int(lines[1])
print(numero_de_autos)
for i in range(2,numero_de_autos+2):
    caracteristicas.append(lines[i])
print(caracteristicas)
nivel.append(caracteristicas)
print(nivel)
```